# set the default text format for node posted by anonymous

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, text-formatting

When a node with body text format as **plain_text** is posted by anonymous user , how do I change it to **full_html** when being edited by admin or authenticated user?

Is there anyway I can edit body fields text_format on the go? like through preprocessing or form hooks?

I have cases where some of the nodes when edited by admin comes with text format selection dropdown, and for some nodes, it does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the node just choose a different text format - there is a select box under the body that lets you choose the text format you want to use.

You can choose which roles are allowed to use which formats at /admin/config/content/formats